# Running script for every string result in range

Tags: excel, xlsx, vba

I'm new to Excel and VBA, so please bear with me.

I've got a macro that:

1. Get string from G1.
2. Search F column for match.
3. If match is found, copy row and paste it to the bottom of data in sheet with same name as string from G1.

But then i need it to:

4. Do the same with string from G2, G3, G4 and so on..

I have to following code:

```
Sub SearchForString()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String
Dim shName As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LSearchValue = Cells(1, 7)
shName = LSearchValue

LSearchRow = 21

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = Worksheets(shName).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If LCopyToRow < 2 Then LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    'If value in column E = LSearchValue, copy entire row to Sheet2
    If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
        Sheets(shName).Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An Error Occured"

End Sub
```

Can somebody help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the below Code

Note : It is assumed that there is no blank cell in your search criteria column i.e. Column "G".

```
Sub SearchForString()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String
Dim shName As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'let's find the  last cell in G column
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i as Integer

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row

for i = 1 to lastRow

LSearchValue = Cells(i, 7)
shName = LSearchValue

LSearchRow = 21

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = Worksheets(shName).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If LCopyToRow < 2 Then LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

'If value in column E = LSearchValue, copy entire row to Sheet2
If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then

    'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
    Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
    Sheets(shName).Select
    Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End If

LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Range("A1").Select

Next

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Hi Amg.

Thanks for the answer, it works great! Only issue is that if i have 3 values and set it to search 4 rows or more, it returns my error message. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I am not getting your problem. Can you elaborate it a littlebit in deapth.

Comment: Sure - I edited my post to show the full code.

When "For i" is set to 7 and I only have values in 3 of the cells, it copies the data and does everything it should, but it runs the Err_execute instead of MsgBox "All matching data has been copied.".

Comment: I have updated the code as per your requirement. now whatever no of cell in G column will be there it will automatically take care of it.